# npm Error while trying to install @squarespace/server package

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, squarespace

I am trying to test out the possibility of using Squarespace developer mode, and I want to develop locally so I need to download their development server. When I try to install the package using "npm install -g @squarespace/server" I continue getting this error message that I can't understand:

```
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:squarespace/server Cloning into bare repository '/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/PublicTrust/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-squarespace-server-0ebf03aa'...
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:squarespace/server ERROR: Repository not found.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:squarespace/server fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:squarespace/server 
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:squarespace/server Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:squarespace/server and the repository exists.
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install squarespace/server
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, stat 'squarespace/server'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "@squarespace/server"
npm ERR! cwd /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/PublicTrust
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.30
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! path squarespace/server
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/PublicTrust/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I cannot figure out what the problem is - something to do with permissions? I am on an iMac OSX 10.9.5.